# Visual Studio - Get memory address of first character in string

Tags: c++, string, assembly, disassembly

I have a C++ code which prints a string into the screen, like this:

```
cout << "Hello, World" << endl
```

What I need to do is to, using the Visual Studio memory disassembler, find the memory address of the first character in that string literal ("Hello, World") (in this case, the letter 'H', and the last one)

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want that? String literals are stored in non-writable memory.

Comment: Just for fun, because I'm learning Assembly language

Comment: Be aware that most OS's will not load the data in the same place on every execution.  Usually, the addresses are either relative or virtual.  For relative addresses, the loader will resolve them when the executable is loaded into memory.  In summary, the addresses will not be the same value each time.

Answer (score 2):

You can print the address with a `cout` (not sure how to do it directly with the disassembler)

```
std::cout << (void*)"Hello, World";
```

Or, if you need to store the string literal,

```
const char* str = "Hello, World";
std::cout << (void*)str;
```

Full example <kbd>[Live on Ideone](http://ideone.com/erPGnA)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char* ptr = "Hello, World";
    std::cout << (void*)ptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << (void*)"Hello, World" << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see in the running example, the string literals `"Hello, World"` and `char* str = "Hello, World"` are actually using the same memory (the compiler is smart enough to realize you have 2 identical string literals, so it only allocates memory for one).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a little bit of assembly. Next code was created with a Visual Studio 2010 C++ console project :

```
void first_char ( char * mystr ) {
short datas;
int addr;
printf( "The string is : %s\n",mystr );
__asm { mov  ax, ds        ;GET DATA SEGMENT.
        mov  datas, ds    
        lea  esi, mystr    ;GET STRING OFFSET.
        mov  addr, esi
      }
printf( "Its address is : %d:%d",datas,addr );
}
```

This is how you can call the previous method:

```
first_char( "Hello, World" );
```

The result will look like this :

[image]